# Is there a way to see the history of how a project was developed?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm new to a position in a company and getting familiar with the different Java projects they have in their bitbucket. As I was reading a lot of code I came to a point where thought the following:

It would help me to see a chart which shows me which classes accrued in which order and which imports where made at a time. Here an example of what would be helpful to me:

- From project x with 20 classes class y was created first with the following imports ... the method xy was created first, then z second and so on.

I think this would be a real benefit for people that have to understand code. Is there anything like that?

Comment: It's called "version control".

Comment: *they have in their bitbucket* - yes. that's a git server. and it is possible to view all revision history **in** bitbucket. google "atlassian bitbucket documentation".

Comment: For getting a high-level grasp of who contributed what and when, there is a fun visualization tool called [Gource](http://gource.io/) available. When talking about individual files, version control history (with "show annotation" from your IDE) is probably what you need to have a look at.